# keras: train a hierarchical categorical + regression model at the same time

Tags: keras, keras-layer

I have the following models:

```
import keras
from keras.layers import Input, Dense
from keras.models import Model

# Joint input layer for both model A and B
inputs = Input(shape=(12,))

# ---------------------------------------
# model_A
x = Dense(64, activation='relu')(inputs)
x = Dense(64, activation='relu')(x)
predictions_A = Dense(3, activation='softmax')(x)
model_A = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=predictions_A)

# ---------------------------------------
# model_B
inputs_B = keras.layers.concatenate([inputs, predictions_A])
x1 = Dense(64, activation='relu')(inputs_B)
x1 = Dense(64, activation='relu')(x1)
predictions_B = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(x1)
model_B = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=predictions_B)
```

And the loss functions for both models are:

```
model_A.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',
              loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])


model_B.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
```

I was able to train the two models separately like below:

```
model_A.fit(my_data_x, pd.get_dummies(my_data['target_categorical'],prefix=['cate_'])) 

model_B.fit(my_data_x, my_data_y)
```

The code is running, but this is not exactly what I wants.
I want the model_A and model_B to be trained "At the same time". That is, model_A uses its own cross-entropy loss function while taking into account the back-prop error from model_B. Is this something possible?

Answer (score 1):

You need a single model with two outputs:

```
model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs = [predictions_A, predictions_B])
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', 
              loss=['categorical_crossentropy', 'mse'],
              metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(my_data_x, 
          [pd.get_dummies(my_data['target_categorical'],prefix=['cate_']),
           my_data_y])
```